# The WinRM service cannot process the request. A command already exists with the command ID specified by the client

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0

When I run the code below whilst debugging in Visual Studio 2015 it works fine. When it gets deployed to IIS, I get the following error at the second `ps.Invoke()` line:

> The WinRM service cannot process the request. A command already exists
>   with the command ID specified by the client.

```
public static PowerShellResponse AddToDistributionGroup(Credentials creds, string groupName, string memberEmail)
{
    PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(creds.Username, creds.Password.ToSecureString());

    WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(Settings.ExchangeServerAutomationUrl), Settings.ExchangeAutomationSchemaName, cred);
    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            //can't pipe OU to Add-DistrubtionGroupMember b/c it blows up w/ "null reference exception" when member already exists

            var group =
                    ps
                        .AddCommand("Get-DistributionGroup")
                            .AddParameter("Identity", groupName)
                            .AddParameter("OrganizationalUnit", creds.GetUserDN())
                        .Invoke()
                        .SingleOrDefault();

            if (group == null)
                return new PowerShellResponse() { Errors = new List<string> { "Group not found." } };

            ps.AddStatement();

            ps.AddCommand("Add-DistributionGroupMember")
                .AddParameter("Identity", ((dynamic)group).Identity)
                .AddParameter("Member", memberEmail);

            ps.Invoke(); //this is where the error shows up

            return ps.GetResponse();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm connecting to Exchange (API Docs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641234(v=exchg.160).aspx) using C# and PowerShell 3.0 trying to add a member to a distribution group in Exchange.

`PowerShellResponse` is a custom class we have, and `ps.GetResponse()` is a custom function to create said `PowerShellResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

Having not been able to find this error discussed anywhere online, the solution I came up with was not calling `ps.Invoke()` twice in one using statement. The following worked fine both locally and once deployed to IIS:

```
public static PowerShellResponse AddToDistributionGroup(Credentials creds, string groupName, string memberEmail)
{
    PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(creds.Username, creds.Password.ToSecureString());

    WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri(Settings.ExchangeServerAutomationUrl), Settings.ExchangeAutomationSchemaName, cred);
    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;

    PSObject group;

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            group =
                    ps
                        .AddCommand("Get-DistributionGroup")
                            .AddParameter("Identity", groupName)
                            .AddParameter("OrganizationalUnit", creds.GetUserDN())
                        .Invoke()
                        .SingleOrDefault();
        }
    }

    //can't pipe OU to Add-DistrubtionGroupMember b/c it blows up w/ "null reference exception" when member already exists
    if (group == null)
        return new PowerShellResponse() { Errors = new List<string> { "Group not found." } };

    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;

            ps.AddCommand("Add-DistributionGroupMember")
                .AddParameter("Identity", ((dynamic)group).Identity)
                .AddParameter("Member", memberEmail);

            ps.Invoke();

            return ps.GetResponse();
        }
    }
}
```